# How does Android system determine scrolling orientation? How to change this behavior?

Tags: scroll, android

I have a TableLayout in a HorizontalScrollView and I put this HorizontalScrollView and some other stuff in a ScrollView, so that this TableLayout can be scrolled both horizontally and vertically.

But the problem is, Android system seems to prefer vertical scrolling. When I swipe exactly horizontally, the TableLayout can be scrolled horizontally. But if I swipe sideways (or diagonally), the Android system will interpret this to be a vertically-scrolling command and the TableLayout will be scrolled vertically.

Is it possible to change the threshold of the scrolling angel interpretation so that if I swipe at the angel smaller than 45 degree (relative to a horizontal line), this would be interpreted as a horizontally-scrolling command and otherwise it would be interpreted as a vertically-scrolling command.

Hope you understand my poor English ;)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you another scrollview somewhere? How is your layout scrolling vertical if your only using a horizontalscrollview?

My experience with scrollviews inside of scrollviews has been poor. However, you can also just intercept the touch events and figure out what it going on. Note that I wouldn't recommend this. I recommend a redesign.

```
onGenericMotionEvent(MotionEvent event)
```

Comment: I put HorizontalScrollView into a ScrollView so that the TableLayout in HorizontalScrollView can be scrolled both horizontally and vertically

Comment: Yeah. That's what I thought. Embedding scrollviews has never lead to a nice UI in my experience. You may want to look into a ViewPager